# V fgner lbh va gur snpr

Tags: riddle

#### What am I?

> Frequently I appear,
>
> Not just here,
>
> Applesauce I make,
>
> Did that hold you up?
>
> Vulnerable I am,
>
> Annoying I can be,
>
> But required I am,
>
> To hide what could ruin,
>
> A soul's own zeal,
>
> For what is frequently here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are

> The rot13 substitution cipher

*Frequently I appear*

> It is used frequently to hide spoiler comments

*Applesauce I make*

> Applesauce as a term can mean nonsense, which is how rot13 text reads

*Vulnerable I am*

> It's an easily breakable cipher

*Annoying I can, But required I am, To hide what could ruin*

> The cipher is used to hide comments which would otherwise spoil puzzles

Additionally

> The title is a rot13 of "I stare you in the face"

Comment: Damn that was fast. I have to think of something more difficult because you guys are too good xd.

Comment: @marsnebulasoup I think your title clue was part of the reason.