# U cant s0lv th!s haha - who am I?

Tags: riddle, word, knowledge, wordplay, cipher

I got a cryptic (or maybe just junk) message in my inbox today:

```
Delivered-To: <marsnebulasoup@me.com>
From: <7u3pu1yq@0sz4aq0.com>
Received: by 3166:673:a796:7652:f6a6:571 with SMTP id 6b7263675f61687a66;
        Thu, 31 Dec 2020 09:34:53 -0800 (PST)
Message-Id: 6368336b2d73336e6472
Signature: 70307a7a30615f677565336e71
Subject: "U cant s0lv th!s haha - who am I?"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Body: "d0wn by th3 drag0ns e$tuary, wh!ch lay al0ng$!d3 3d!th'$ 3!ght alpacas, n!n3ty-tw0 fact0r!3$ pr0duc3d $3v3n$ 0f f!t $!xty-$3v3n$"
```

Here's the body of the message:

> d0wn by th3 drag0ns e\$tuary, wh!ch lay al0ng\$!d3 3d!ths 3!ght alpacas, n!n3ty-tw0 fact0r!3\$ pr0duc3d \$3v3n\$ 0f f!t \$!xty-\$3v3n\$

It just looks like spam to me, but I'm not sure, because there seems to be a sort of pattern here, but I'm at a loss. The subject asks "Who am I?", but it doesn't seem that there's anything here that says who they are. Can you help?

**Hint 1**

> As I mentioned in the comments, every part (well almost) of the puzzle (the puzzle is everything in the code block, so you don't really have to look at the rest) is related to it some**h**ow.

**Hint 2**

> For **ex**ample, the line:
>  "Received: by 3166:673:a796:7652:f6a6:571 with SMTP id 6b7263675f61687a66;" contains a hint for **t**h**e** body's te**xt**.

**Hint 3**

> Also, the last line of the puzzle, which seems like side-commentry, that everyone has chose to focus on, is also a clue, but, apparently, not a very good one, if that's the first thing that's noticed. It was supposed to be discreetly linking this puzzle to another, which has a (rather blatant) clue for this (and a deeper) part of this puzzle.

**Hint 4**

> The numbers (and symbols) within words are there to confuse you. That said, (as I implied in the comments) you should be able to extract a hexadecimal number from the body and thereby (necessarily) a decimal one, for which the "From" hint will be relevant. The Signature hint is not relevant until you've figured out what the body means.

**Hint 5**

> The "From" clue is meant to just point you in the right direction when it comes to solving the number. So don't think of specific things from *The Mandalorian*, but rather think broadly: what is *The Mandalorian* part of? I can say that you don't need to know anything about the *Star Wars* universe itself to solve this, though some info about the shows/movies themselves might be required.

**Hint 6**

> It is a person

---

*Hopefully this puzzle will be more difficult than the [previous one I posted](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106127/v-fgner-lbh-va-gur-snpr), which was solved in like 30 minutes*

---

***I've accepted @Smartest1here's answer because it contains the right solution, though it's only a partial answer. @xhienne deserves credit, though, since they were the one who got to that point in the first place. See their answer for the reasoning behind the puzzle.***

Comment: Are you _sure_ this is a riddle? We define riddle as a puzzles that gives indirect clues towards an object/concept, not just any puzzle. They're usually formatted as a poem-like thing.

Comment: @bobble - It's a non-rhyming riddle, if you will. It has everything you mentioned btw--except the poem-like formatting

Comment: Also, I'm going to remove your meta-comment about difficulty because it isn't relevant to the question. You may be interested in this [meta-post](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2947) about the many-eyes effect.

Comment: It is though. Every part of the puzzle is related to it in some way or another

Comment: If it's integral to the puzzle, why is it set by itself? You can add it back in, but it does give the impression of side commentary, which isn't allowed here.

Comment: But I've seen a lot of puzzle give side-commentary, like this one: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/105969/48389

Comment: @marsnebulasoup If that comment is _part of the puzzle_ then of course it should stay. But if it's just saying what it seems to be saying, it isn't really adding anything. I'm not sure it's particularly worth the trouble of editing to remove it (and I think the inconsistency you complain about is just a matter of people not always bothering to do marginal tidy-ups) but I'm pretty sure the puzzle would be better without it.

Comment: Can we have a hint?

Comment: @Smartest1Here - I've added a hint...it may or may not be relevant though, depending how far you are in solving the puzzle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Partial answer maybe I am barking up the wrong tree here.

Following hint 4, The IPv6 part and the SMTP ID part:

> d0wn by th3 drag0ns e\$tuary, wh!ch lay al0ng\$!d3 3d!ths 3!ght alpacas, n!n3ty-tw0 fact0r!3\$ pr0duc3d \$3v3n\$ 0f f!t \$!xty-\$3v3n\$

> Taking the first letters of Down by gets us DB Dragon's Estuary one gets DB+DE, laying alongside Edith's eight alapacas, one gets DBDE+AE8A, ninety-two factories DBDEAEA8A+92F produced sevens DBDAE8A92F+7 of fit sixty-sevens DBDEAE8A92F7+F67. This produces the hexadecimal number DBDEAE8A92F7F67.

Is the person you are looking for:

> Anthony Daniels who voiced C3PO, the android that has appeared in all the 9 star wars films?

Comment: Not quite...guvax nobhg jung yrggref ner urk ahzoref

Comment: Probably dbdea8a92f7f67. First letters if hex, ignore digits as per hints, resolve written-out numbers.

Comment: I was just doing that:-)

Comment: 3 of "3d!ths" probably shouldn't count as an E

Comment: @LukusRotter, Smartest1here - You're in the right track...keep going...see hint 4 also

Comment: Orsber lbh pbaireg gur obql gb urk, pbaireg vg gb pyrne grkg...

Comment: So I was right before?

Comment: @Smartest1here - Yes

Comment: @Smartest1here - see hint five

Comment: @Smartest1here - You got it. I'm not sure which answer to accept now since yours is only a partial one.

Comment: I literally to the right one just changed my answer before you finished your comment.

Comment: I remembered the same situation with the No-Sensa puzzle on here recently.

Comment: It is up to you

Comment: In that case, I think I'll accept yours, since it actually has the right answer, and I'll put a not in the question that xhienne's has the reasoning behind it.

Comment: I will give Xhienne a bounty if you do that.

Comment: @Smartest1here Many thanks, that's very kind of you, but a bounty is far too much, I can't accept that. This is all just a game. Just copy-pate my answer in yours, adapt the text and enjoy. Cheers

Comment: Well I don't think I can revese it.

Comment: Then, attribute the bounty to your own answer ;-)

Answer (score 6):

Who are you? Hmmm, I bet you are:

> [George Lucas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Lucas), the creator of the Star Wars universe.

`Delivered-To: <marsnebulasoup@me.com>`

> Not relevant, per OP's comment below. <s>OK, this is the original poster's name. Maybe it hides something? The three words `mars` `nebula` `soup` don't suggest anything to me. They might be an anagram but I didn't find it out. They also might be of some use later (see below).</s>

`From: <7u3pu1yq@0sz4aq0.com>`

> If you rot13 the address, you get `7h3ch1ld@0fm4nd0.pbz` ("The child of Mando")
>  Refers to [Grogu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grogu) (Baby Yoda), the adoptive child of [The Mandalorian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mandalorian_(character)).

`Received: by 3166:673:a796:7652:f6a6:571 with SMTP id 6b7263675f61687a66;`

The IPv6 part must be seen as

> a sequence of ASCII codes in hexadecimal:
>  `3166:673:a796:7652:f6a6:571`
>  => 0x31 0x66 0x67 0x3a 0x79 0x67 0x65 0x2f 0x6a 0x65 0x71
>  => `1fg:yge/jeq`
>  ... which is the rot13 encoding of `1st:ltr/wrd` ("first letter of each word")
>  As for which words it is referring to, <s>I guess it is the text in the body part but keep in mind those could be the three words in the Delivered-To: field (mars, nebula, soup => mns)</s> hint #2 tells us this is the body part.

The SMTP ID part

> follows the same encoding:
>  `6b7263675f61687a66`
>  => 0x6b 0x72 0x63 0x67 0x5f 0x61 0x68 0x7a 0x66
>  =>  `krcg_ahzf`
>  ... which is the rot13 encoding of `xept_nums` ("except numbers")

`Message-Id: 6368336b2d73336e6472`

> This too is a sequence of hex ASCII codes:
>  `6368336b2d73336e6472`
>  => 0x63 0x68 0x33 0x6b 0x2d 0x73 0x33 0x6e 0x64 0x72
>  => `ch3k-s3ndr` ("check sender" where sender is the From: line)

`Signature: 70307a7a30615f677565336e71`

> Same encoding as the Received: line.
>  `70307a7a30615f677565336e71`
>  => 0x70 0x30 0x7a 0x7a 0x30 0x61 0x5f 0x67 0x75 0x65 0x33 0x6e 0x71
>  => `p0zz0a_gue3nq`
>  ... which is the rot13 encoding of `c0mm0n_thr3ad` ("common thread")
>
>  <s>SMTP-wise, a thread may refer to `References:` and `In-Reply-To:` header lines which are absent here, so it must be something else (unconvincingly: maybe a wordplay that alludes to [Ariadne's thread](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ariadne%27s_thread_(logic))?).</s>

`Subject: "U cant s0lv th!s haha - who am I?"`

> Didn't see anything special. Probably just the goal of the riddle.

`Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8`

> Nothing special, this is an expected mail header

`Body: "d0wn by th3 drag0ns e$tuary, wh!ch lay al0ng$!d3 3d!th'$ 3!ght alpacas, n!n3ty-tw0 fact0r!3$ pr0duc3d $3v3n$ 0f f!t $!xty-$3v3n$"`

In clear text: "Down by the dragons estuary, which lay alongside Edith's eight alpacas, ninety-two factories produced sevens of fit sixty-sevens"

> The rule here, according to the decoded `Received:` line, is to consider only the first letter of each word that is not a number.
>  You get: d b t d e w l a e 8 a 92 f p 7 o f 67
>
>  If we only keep the valid hexadecimal digits (hints #1, #2 and #4) then we get this big hex number:
>  DBDEAE8A92F7F67
>
>  ... which translates to this decimal number:
>  990205778083151719

What does this decimal number means? How is it special?

> It contains the years of the nine Star Wars episodes, in the chronological order of the story ("common thread", as suggested by the `Signature:` line):
>  19**99** The Phantom Menace
>  20**02** Attack of the Clones
>  20**05** Revenge of the Sith
>  19**77** Star Wars
>  19**80** The Empire Strikes Back
>  19**83** Return of the Jedi
>  20**15** The Force Awakens
>  20**17** The Last Jedi
>  20**19** The Rise of Skywalker

Hint #1 and #2:

> ... refer to the **hex**adecimal encoding of the **text**.

Hint #3 and footnote:

> ... refer to the rot13 encoding.

Comment: So, I just realized that when I was copy/pasting parts of the puzzle from my computer to PSE, I must have missed a line (the Signature one) somehow. I've updated the puzzle, and luckily it's not an integral part of the puzzle yet; seeing how far your partial answer has gone.

Comment: Anyways, rot13(lbh'er zbfgyl ba gur evtug genpx. V jvyy fnl gung gur qryvirerq-gb nqqerff vf abg eryrinag, naq gur   erprvirq-ol uvagf jrer zrnag sbe gur obql, naq qrpbqvat gur obql erdhverf fbzr xabjyrqtr bs urknqrpvzny ahzoref naq ubj gurl ner ercerfragrq.)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Amended my answer to take them into account, especially the Signature line. rot13(V thrff zl urk fxvyyf ner tbbq rabhtu ohg V zhfg svefg svaq jurer gur urknqrpvzny uvqrf vafvqr gur obql... Naljnl, vs gur xabjyrqtr gnt ersref gb Gur Znaqnybevna be Fgne Jnef havirefr, V'z cerggl fher V jba'g fbyir guvf chmmyr.)

Comment: Nf V fnvq rneyvre, gur Fvtangher gnt vf n uvag sbe n qrrcre cneg bs gur chmmyr abg lrg ernpurq. Nyfb juvyr gur chmmyr vf boivbhfyl fbzrubj eryngrq gb Fgne Jnef be gur Znaqnybevna, lbh qba'g unir gb or n Fgne Jnef ohss gb fbyir gur chmmyr...gur xabjyrqtr gnt whfg zrnaf vg gnxr n ovg bs fgengrtvp Tbbtyvat :Q

Comment: My idea (as a noob amature) for the next step, vf gung gur 'krcg_ahzf' cneg nyfb ersref gb gur qrpbqvat bs gur obql, zrnavat ahzoref (3!tug) fubhyq or vtaberq, nf jryy nf ahzoref ng gur fgneg bs n jbeq (3q!gu'$). Guvf ynfg vqrn vf nf gur `r` ng gur fgneg bs `r$ghnel` vf abg n 3, juvyr nyy bguref ner. Vs lbh purpx nyy gur erznvavat svefg yrggref, lbh trg `qogqrjynnscs`, ohg V unir abg sbhaq nalguvat jvgu gurfr yrggref rvgure.

Comment: @XanderL - See the fourth hint I just posted; it should help.

Comment: @xhienne - Unfortunately, not what I was thinking, *but*,  lbh'ir tbg onfvpnyyl rirelguvat evtug hc hagvy ynfg cneg (vg'f abg Trbetr Yhpnf). V zrnag sbe gur pbzzba guernq uvag gb or hfrq nsgre lbh svtherq bhg gung gur ahzore jnf n yvfg bs Fgne Jnef zbivrf....see my sixth hint also

Comment: @marsnebulasoup Sorry, hint #6 doesn't help much. I'm probably not familiar enough with Stars Wars to guess more. I was hesitating between rot13(Trbetr Yhpnf naq Lbqn) but frankly I don't have a very strong reason to choose the latter instead. Obviously, I miss the knowledge required to follow the right thread ;-)